# Ayuda! diferencia entre form action y $http.post()

Tags: html, c#, angularjs, http-post

Buen día, tengo un formulario en el cual los valores que capturo en el necesito enviarlos a un controlador. Dicho controlador en mvc asp.net me retorna una nueva vista como respuesta.

Mi pregunta es, mediante $http.post(), puedo obtener esa vista que me retorna el controlador?. o necesariamente debo utilizar el form action desde el HTML para obtener esa nueva vista?

Asi como lo tengo, realiza la petición post, el controlador hace lo que tiene que hacer, pero no me retorna la nueva view().

**Este es mi formulario:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>DATOS</h1>
<p class="lead">Ingrese datos: </p>
    <p class="a"> Codigo: <input type="text" id="codigo"/></p>
    <p class="badge"> Nombres: <input type="text" id="nombres"/></p>
    <p class="caption"> Apellidos: <input type="text"id="apellidos" /></p>
    <p class="danger"> Correo: <input type="text" id="correo" /></p>
    <p class="help-block"> Estado: <input type="number" id="estado"/></p>
    <button ng-click="registrar()" name="registrar"> REGISTRAR </button>
```

**Este es el codigo que tengo para la petición en $http.post**

```
angular.module("MyApp", [])
.controller("FirstController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.registrar = function () {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST', url: '/Cliente/Create',
            data: {
                "codigo": document.getElementById("codigo").value,
                "nombres": document.getElementById("nombres").value,
                "apellidos": document.getElementById("apellidos").value,
                "correo": document.getElementById("correo").value,
                "estado": document.getElementById("estado").value
            }
        };
        $http(req).then(function (res) {
        });
    };
});
```

**Y este es mi controlador:**

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "codigo,nombres,apellidos,correo,estado")] clientes e)
    {
            clientes q = new clientes();
            q.create(e);

        return View(q);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tanto el `Form` como el `$http` te devolverán lo que sea que envíe el servidor como respuesta.

La diferencia entre los dos es que con el `form` la respuesta se recibe como una nueva página.

Y con `$http` lo mismo que con ajax, la respuesta llega como un `callback` a un objecto en javascript / angular sin refrescar la página.